# ASP.NET Core 2.1 RedirectToAction appends TempData to url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is my save function. It is under a controller called Repositories. When I save a new Repository, it appends this to my url:

> https://localhost:44325/Repositories/Repositories?TempData=%5BSuccess,%20Repository%20Created%5D&ViewBag=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.DynamicViewData&HttpContext=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext&Request=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest&Response=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpResponse&RouteData=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteData&ModelState=%5BName,%20Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary%2BModelStateNode%5D&ControllerContext=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext&MetadataProvider=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadataProvider&ModelBinderFactory=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelBinderFactory&Url=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.UrlHelper&ObjectValidator=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultObjectValidator&User=System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal

I understand that it has something to do with RedirectToAction("Index",this) as when I use Redirect("Index"), the url just ends with a /Index. However, I would like the Index word to be hidden and RedirectToAction does that. How can I solve this issue?

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Save(CreateRepositoryViewModel Input)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Create", Input);
    }
    var directory = directoriesController.Create(Input);
    if (directory != null)
    {
        Input.Path = directory;
        var result = repositoriesData.Save(Input);
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["Error"] = "Repository Creation" + LoggingGlobals.Error;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", this);
    }
    TempData["Success"] = "Repository " + LoggingGlobals.Create;
    return RedirectToAction("Index", this);
}
```

Comment: What is your controller name? Are you trying to to pass the `TempData` from `Save` method to `Index` method?

Comment: The URL structure seem suspicious, normally it should show `https://localhost:44325/Repositories/Index`, `https://localhost:44325/Repositories` or somewhat like that. I think the `TempData` contents should not be passed as part of query string.

Comment: No! Problem is in the `this` keyword! I have answer of this question but I am waiting for the comment from questioner.

Comment: Controller name is Repositories.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto the Tempdata is not going into the query string

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("Index", this);` => the second parameter is `routeValues`, which represented in query string. Passing `this` contains `ControllerBase` instance, which contains model state and `TempData`.

Comment: What can I pass instead?

Comment: You are basically looking at all the controller properties passed as the data model.

Comment: Why are you passing `this` to begin with?

Comment: I thought I was passing the Controller that I wanted to redirect to instead of always passing the name.

Comment: Look at the API doc and you see that when not using string it maps to the overload that takes object as second parameter which represents the routeValues https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: There is one that is like this RedirectToAction(String, String) that sets the second input as the controllername

Comment: Correct but you did not invoke that. `this` will pass the object, not its name. If the action is within the same controller then there is no need to pass the name. It will be inferred.

Comment: I see. I need to set the controller name somewhere and reuse it then

Comment: No need to set the name anywhere. The framework will get that from reflection.

Comment: instead of confusing everyone here I'd recommend that it's faster to learn some basics by going thru a tutorial (or 2) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in this return statement:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", this);
```

According to [RedirectToAction overloads list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_RedirectToAction_System_String_System_Object_), the second parameter may contain `routeValues` while an object passed to it instead of string:

```
public virtual RedirectToActionResult RedirectToAction (string actionName, object routeValues)
```

Hence, you're actually passing `ControllerBase` instance as `routeValues` parameter. Therefore, you should provide controller name instead:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Repositories");
```

If you want to pass `routeValues` parameter together with controller name, use `RedirectToAction` with [3 overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_RedirectToAction_System_String_System_String_System_Object_) like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Repositories", new { parameterName = "value" });
```

**Note:**

The `RedirectToAction` uses **HTTP GET** method, which passed route parameters as query string, therefore a viewmodel object doesn't fit into that. You should use another `TempData` or `Session` state instance to pass the viewmodel object to another controller.

```
TempData["ViewModel"] = Input;
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Repositories");
```

Comment: TempData["Error"]  only takes a string

Comment: You can store any object inside `TempData` with various key names, not just a string. If you want to pass that as query string, follow the 3-overload version of `RedirectToAction`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is already addressed in another answer.

I will address

> However, I would like the Index word to be hidden

With attribute routing, you can set an empty route template

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class RepositoriesController {


    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")] //GET Repositories
    [Route("[action]")] //GET Repositories/Index
    public IActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    //...
}
```

That way when invoking `return RedirectToAction("Index")`, the generated URL will be what was configured in the route template.

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)